# Rails 3. ActiveAdmin filter for child association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have shipments has one invoice; and invoice belongs to shipments. When I try to do this...

```
filter :customer, :collection => proc {(Customer.all).map{|c| [c.company_name, c.id]}}
```

O get this error `(Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'invoices.customer_id'`.

The customer_id column is actually on the shipments table. Since invoice belongs to shipment, I usually access the customer_id by doing `invoice.shipment.customer_id`. But I don't know how to implement this to create an activeadmin filter.

Complete error: `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: invoices.customer_id: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT count_column) FROM (SELECT  "invoices"."id" AS count_column FROM "invoices" LEFT OUTER JOIN "customers" ON "customers"."id" = "invoices"."customer_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "shipments" ON "shipments"."id" = "invoices"."shipment_id" WHERE "customers"."id" = 2 LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count`

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a [Nested Attribute](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)?

Comment: still get `no such column: invoices.customer_id`